# SQL Query for searching table 'C' records only if records from table 'A' has specific values

Tags: sql-server-2012

I Have Three Tables, TBL-A, TBL-B, TBL-C, TBL-D

TBL A has records for userstatus

```
RECID    USRID    USERSTAT    USRNAME
1        1        1           JOHN
2        5        1           HARRY
3        6        4           GARY
```

TBL B has user details

```
RECID   USRID   FNAME  MNAME  LNAME MOBNO
1        1      JOHN   F      MOSES 1234567
2        2      MARY          MOSES 5421679
3        5      HARRY         KENEDY 1234567
4        6      GARY          MOLE   1234567
```

TBL C has additional details only for the user having CAT as 1(in Table A)

```
RECID   USRID   GRPID
1       1       2
2       5       4
```

TBL D has details of GRP ID

```
GRPID   GRPNAME GRPDETAIL
 1      group1   FIRSTGROUP
 2      group2   SECOND GROUP
 4      group4   FOURTH GROUP
```

On basis of user input of mobno(TBL B) all the record having mobno='xxxxx' along with corresponding records of TBL A(userstat), TBL B(FName, Mname, Lname), TBL C(GRPID)-(if existing else output as null or blank), TBL D (GRPNAME,GRPDETAILS)-(if existing else output as null or blank).
should be searched.

PLS Help

Comment: You can just do this with regular joins and a WHERE clause, specifying the TBLA filter.

Comment: That is 4 tables and that is an odd data design

Answer (score 0):

Vivek - just use (Left or Right) outer joins. This will make sure that the null values will be shown if the data does not exist within the joined table.

Comment: Thanks dear, but still couldn't get the same, actually not very fluent with sql, pls can u help with a sample query illustrating what you said. Thanks